# Issue while using wrapper class in angular js

Tags: apex, visualforce, angularjs

I am trying to learn creating forms in vf pages using angular js. Below is the code i am trying to write -

There are errors which i am getting in console -

```
 $scope.contactwraplist = [ContactWrapper:[c=Contact:{}, contactEmails=(ContactEmail:[c1=Contact:{}, wrapperIdContactEmail=153f34a5-f4f2-c841-266e-02a0d10551ff]), wrapperId=c18446c2-c30e-14f4-1801-fc9b2ad8dd14]]

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Cannot read property 'generateUrl' of undefined
```

Vf page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="accountcontactwrapperclass" showHeader="false">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js">
            </script>
        </head>
        <script>

            var App = angular.module('myApp', []);

            App.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {   

                $scope.contactwraplist = {!contactWrapperlist}
            });
            </script>
            <body ng-app="myApp" class="container" ng-controller="myctrl">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactwraplist | filter:query">          
                        <td> <input type="text" required="true" name="LastName" ng-model="contact.c.LastName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="button" ng-click="SaveAll()" value="Save"/>
            </body>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class -

```
public class accountcontactwrapperclass {

    public Account acc {get;set;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> contactWrapperlist {get;set;}
    public String wrapperId {get; set;}

    public accountcontactwrapperclass (ApexPages.StandardController controller){

        contactWrapperlist = new List<ContactWrapper>(); 
    }

    public class ContactWrapper{
        public Contact c {get;set;}
        public string wrapperId {get;set;}
        public List<ContactEmail> contactEmails {get;set;}
        public ContactWrapper(){
            Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
            String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
            wrapperId = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
          contactEmails = new List<ContactEmail>();
            c = new Contact();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found it easier to use JSON. You can do something like the following in your Apex controller:

```
String myWrappersJSON { get; private set; }

// myWrappersJSON = JSON.serialize(contactWrapperList);
```

And then in your Javascript:

```
var myWrappers = JSON.parse("{!myWrappersJSON}");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want or need to work with AngularJS (or any other JS framework) I would suggest you to use [Visualforce Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) instead. With this approach you will have to manipulate the state of your data in Angular, but you'll be able to post it to the platform in a much easier way using JSON.

To call a method on your page using VFRemoting, you do something like this:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.APEXCLASS.APEXMETHOD}',
  data,
  function (result, event) {
    if (event.statusCode == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(result)
      // parse the response from the server here
      // and do what you need to do ;)
    }
    $scope.$apply()
  }, { escape : false })
```

If you do it this way remember to use Angular's `$scope.$apply()` to force it to rerender when your call (because the call itself is async, but the rendering by Angular is synchronous).